# How to merge PDF-files with php if you get your pdf filenames out of a database?

Tags: php, pdf, merge

Hello I want to get my pdf filenames out of my database and merge them only I got 2 problems in my database are names but not with ".pdf" after it how can I set it after the filename when i get it in an array.
And my second problem is how can I merge them?

```php
<?php

// run query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT antwoord_id FROM antwoordklant WHERE gebruiker_id = ('" . $id . "')");

// set array
$filearray = array();

// look through query
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // add each row returned into an array
    $filearray[] = $row;

    // OR just echo the data:
    echo $row['antwoord_id']; // etc
}

// debug:
print_r($filearray);               // show all array data
echo $filearray[0]['antwoord_id']; // print the first rows username

$datadir = "/home/easyhous/public_html/architectenplan/pdf";
$outputName = $datadir."merged.pdf";

$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";
//Add each pdf file to the end of the command
foreach($filearray as $file) {
    $cmd .= $file." ";
}
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: So do you want to only merge the Filenames or the Filenames AND the Files?

Comment: I only want to merge the files actually but for that I need the Filenames and they can always be diffrent. so when i got the filenames out of my database I want to merge the files with the same name in my map

Answer (score 0):

Write instead of

```
$filearray[] = $row;
```

this

```
$filearray[] = array($row['antwoord_id'], $row['filename'].'.pdf', $row['foo'], ... );
```

Then you can edit all Variables that come out of the Database directly.

Comment: thanks thats how i put the ".pdf" after thats the first problem solved. but how can I merge al the pdf files where the name are the same i get out of my database as in my map where al the pdf files are?